# Creating Firebase Auth observer using openUI5

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, sapui5

I apologize if this is a newbie question, but I never worked with an observer, and I am finding hard to understand how to create it.
I have developed a webapp in Firebase which uses openUI5.  So the app has the structure of that framework:

- webapp folder

  - index.html
  - component.js
  - manifest.json
  - view folder

    - App.view.xml
  - controller folder

    - App.controller.js

That is the file structure, so you can have a quick snapshot.

I am already able to use federated authentication of Google with Firebase.  I can log in and out.
But I wanted to use the firebase Auth observer in order to update a JSON Model of the app (with user DisplayName and stuff like that)

In essence, I understand that I should define the observer in the component.js file, but since I do not know how to make that work, instead I created the following in the index.html:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   var oModel = this.getModel();
   if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    MessageToast.show(oModel.user.displayName);
    oModel.user.displayName = user.displayName;

   } else {
    // No user is signed in.
   }
  });
 </script>
```

But that definition is throwing me the following error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined*

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: while defining the script, I do not need the **type="text/javascript"**

I took that away and could get going.